# Opinion on dividing analogous/similar attributes for large stores

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm taking on a project for a web store which contains a large amount of SKU's including many different type of products (store for clothing/apparel & motorcycle parts / accessories).

Currently the backend is somewhat sloppy with many configurable products built on varying attributes that are the same in nature, just have different names.  For example:

"Size" and "Apparel Size".  Some products use Size, and some use Apparel Size, etc.

I think this was done by previous developers to try and create a more organizational structure due to the how many attribute values exist within each.

Should you divide attributes up like this or is it just more headache in the long run?  Is it correct to have a universal "Size" attribute for all clothing that contains various values such as Small / Medium / Large / 32 / 33 / 35 etc.

It seems like Magento 1.9.1 seems intent on putting everything into 1 in regards to Color Swatches, as you can only use 1 option on the catalog thumbnails.